# Generating an identical sequence of random tensorflow operations for parallel instances

Tags: python, tensorflow, random

I'm trying to write my own data generator for an image segmentation task in order to have more control over the transformations that I can apply. To start, I'm writing a toy generator that outputs a randomly cropped image using tf.image.random_crop:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image as k_img
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

class DataGen:
    seed=1
    def __init__(self,seed=1):
        self.seed = seed

    def flow(self):
        #tf.random.set_seed(self.seed)
        img = np.asarray(k_img.load_img('data/train/images/all/image.png',color_mode='grayscale'))
        while(True):
            img_crop = tf.image.random_crop(img,(32,32),seed=self.seed)
                        yield img_crop
```

The use case looks like this:

```
gen = DataGen(1234).flow()
gen2 = DataGen(1234).flow()
fig = plt.figure()
#gen
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.imshow(next(gen))
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.imshow(next(gen))
#gen2
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.imshow(next(gen2))
plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.imshow(next(gen2))
```

The desired behavior is for image 1 & 3 to be the same and for image 2 & 4 to be the same. However, setting the seeds within tf.image.random_crop in this context does not do this--nothing is repeated. Setting tf.random.set_seed (commented out) does enforce a repeatable sequence, but it is global rather than local.

How do I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: You are missing some pieces of code, like `import tensorflow as tf` and `gen = DataGen(1234).flow()`. Can you add **all** you're code for **reproducibility**, and make sure it works on it's own (of course given there's an image at the specified path.

Comment: @JayMody Thanks, I fixed it.